# creating new laravel application on mac by laravel installer

Tags: bash, laravel, terminal, osx-yosemite

I have been strugling to create an application with laravel installer from terminal. 
I have globally installed composer and laravel.. 
however i constantly get this error:

[image: my terminal screenshot]

If you check at the bottom of the screenshot you can see -bash: new: command not found however laravel command is being executed perfectly. My osx version is 10.10.2. Macbook pro.

Any help will be appreciated.

Another question (bit out of the topic)
Is git inbuild in mac osx? 
Cuz i hadn't installed it but it shows all of its commands.

Regards,

=======================
I created alias for composer and laravel in .bash_profile and .bashrc and it worked however now I'm getting this error :

Prajwols-MacBook-Pro:htdocs prajwol$ laravel new test
Crafting application...

Warning: ZipArchive::extractTo(): Invalid or unitialized Zip object in /Users/prajwol/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php on line 99

Warning: ZipArchive::close(): Invalid or unitialized Zip object in /Users/prajwol/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php on line 101

Application ready! Build something amazing.

Result : An empty folder is created called test in destination folder.

Comment: Why not download zip from github and do composer update

Comment: I want to learn this way..

Comment: Visit this: http://laravel.io/forum/03-23-2014-laravel-installation-command-not-found?page=1, might help

Comment: Hi gaurav.. thanks but its not permission issue.. neither laravel command issue. I am having trouble with the laravel new command..

Comment: I think that you should provide the name, like: `laravel new appname`

Comment: yes..  i was testing if new command is available or not.. however i fixed this issue and now I'm able to create laravel folder but i get empty folder.

Answer (score 1):

The command needs a project name: `laravel new <NAME>`. Like `laravel new blog`. This will create a new laravel project in a new `blog` directory in the current path.

Answer (score 0):

1. ```
   $ brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php
   $ brew install php72
   ```
2. Install composer

   ```
   $ php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
   $ php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
   ```
3. Install Laravel

   ```
   $ composer global require "laravel/installer"
   $ composer global -vvv require "laravel/installer"
   ```

now run command

```
composer
```

Comment: Please add some relevant information about the code mentioned. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/19882999).